# Check if column or diagonal in matrix equals to something

Tags: python, matrix

I can use this code to check if a row in a matrix = x:

```
q = [[1,2,1],[1,2,1],[2,1,2]]
answer = [sum(row) for row in q]
for i in range(0, len(q)):
    if answer[i] == 6:
        print "Player 2 won!"
    if answer[i] == 3:
        print "Player 1 won!"
    if answer[i] != 6 and 3:
        print "It's a tie!"
```

How can I check if my matrix has a diagonal or column that = x, without using Numpy (Is there a mathematical way to do it as shown above?)

Example: (X = something that doesn't matter)

`q = [[1,2,1]
     [1,1,1]
     [1,1,2]]`
 Should print `[4,3,5]` (The Sum of the 2nd row)

```
[[1,X,X],
[X,1,X]
[X,X,1]]
```

Should print `Diagonal`

`q = [[X,X,1]
     [X,1,X]
     [1,X,X]]`
 Should print `Other Diagonal`

`q = [[1,X,X]
     [X,1,X]
     [X,1,X]]`
 Should do nothing

`q = [[X,1,X]
     [X,1,X]
     [X,1,X]]`
 Should print `Horizontal`

[image: How the matrix should have its "winning conditions"]

Comment: Why should the second one print Diagonal?

Comment: Please post per case some justification and also show what you tried...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the question.